# In location-based Ar.js position is not accurate

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

1

I'm using ar.js/a-farme to put GPS entities My problem is that the position of the entities is not accurate and it is moving with me (not stable).I tried adding minDistance,maxDistance etc to gps-camera and gps-projected-camera.still the problem exist.help me to solve my problem

this is my code

```
<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" embedded arjs="sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;">
    <a-box color="yellow" scale="5 5 5"
        gps-projected-entity-place="latitude: 10.0025406014834; longitude: 76.340856430411" />
    <a-text value="This content will always face you." look-at="[gps-camera]" scale="5 5 5"
        gps-entity-place="latitude: 10.0025406014834; longitude: 76.340856430411;"></a-text>
    <a-camera id='camera1' look-controls-enabled='false' arjs-look-controls='smoothingFactor: 0.1'
        gps-camera='gpsMaxDistance: 5' rotation-reader> </a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

in this code the text will appear where ever i go,
it is not staying  at one place.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.